# Ssh with socks proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, socks

I'm trying to connect to a remote shell A using ssh through a socks5 proxy server.
I tried

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand='nc -X 5 -x socks5_proxy_ip:1080 %h %p' user@A
```

Is there something I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: you tried it and it worked? probably not. so you tried it and it failed. how did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

Something you might be doing wrong?  Well if it's not working I'm going to have to assume so.

Install socat and use that to pipe data between SSH and the SOCKS proxy.  When I've done it I've set the commands in the SSH config file.  Once socat is installed configure something like this in your ~/.ssh/config file:

```
Host sshsocks
Hostname a.b.c.d
User username
Port 22
CheckHostIP no
Compression yes
Protocol 2
ProxyCommand socat STDIO SOCKS4A:localhost:%h:%p,socksport=NNNN
```

Change "sshsocks" to the hostname or nickname for the server you're connecting to.  Change "a.b.c.d" to the IP address of the server you're connecting to.  Change "username" to your username.  Change "NNNN" to the port of the SOCKS server (probably 1080, based on your example).  You may want to experiment with using both SOCKS4A and SOCKS5 connections through socat.

For additional SSH port tunneling or X server connections, see the man page for SSH.